# Get val of element multiple forms at one page with jQuery

Tags: jquery

For example i have 3 forms on one page. If i click i want to get the value of the input test 2 from that specific form in a document ready.

How can i achieve that?

```
<form action="" method="post" class="comment-form">
    <input name="test1" class="test1" type="text" value="">
    <input name="test2" class="test2" type="text" value="">
    <input name="test3" class="test3" type="text" value="">
    <input name="submit" class="submitform" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form action="" method="post" class="comment-form">
    <input name="test1" class="test1" type="text" value="">
    <input name="test2" class="test2" type="text" value="">
    <input name="test3" class="test3" type="text" value="">
    <input name="submit" class="submitform" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form action="" method="post" class="comment-form">
    <input name="test1" class="test1" type="text" value="">
    <input name="test2" class="test2" type="text" value="">
    <input name="test3" class="test3" type="text" value="">
    <input name="submit" class="submitform" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

```js
$('.submitform').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ???---???
});
```

Comment: give different names for input field

Comment: @PranavMS ... there are...?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki why? Each input has it's own name within the `form`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, to achieve this you should hook the event to the `submit` event of the `form`, not the click of the button.

From there you can use the `this` keyword to reference the form which was submit, then `find()` to get the required input. Try this:

```js
$('.comment-form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var test2 = $(this).find('input[name="test2"]').val();
  console.log(test2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" class="comment-form">
  <input name="test1" class="test1" type="text" value="">
  <input name="test2" class="test1" type="text" value="1">
  <input name="test3" class="test1" type="text" value="">
  <input name="submit" class="submitform" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form action="" method="post" class="comment-form">
  <input name="test1" class="test1" type="text" value="">
  <input name="test2" class="test1" type="text" value="2">
  <input name="test3" class="test1" type="text" value="">
  <input name="submit" class="submitform" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form action="" method="post" class="comment-form">
  <input name="test1" class="test1" type="text" value="">
  <input name="test2" class="test1" type="text" value="3">
  <input name="test3" class="test1" type="text" value="">
  <input name="submit" class="submitform" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thnx mate! Works!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `form` and `submit` event to fetch the values of the relevant fields:

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log('Value of test2: ' + $(this).find('input[name=test2]').val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" class="comment-form">
  <input name="test1" class="test1" type="text" value="">
  <input name="test2" class="test1" type="text" value="">
  <input name="test3" class="test1" type="text" value="">
  <input name="submit" class="submitform" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form action="" method="post" class="comment-form">
  <input name="test1" class="test1" type="text" value="">
  <input name="test2" class="test1" type="text" value="">
  <input name="test3" class="test1" type="text" value="">
  <input name="submit" class="submitform" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form action="" method="post" class="comment-form">
  <input name="test1" class="test1" type="text" value="">
  <input name="test2" class="test1" type="text" value="">
  <input name="test3" class="test1" type="text" value="">
  <input name="submit" class="submitform" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thnx, this also a good answer, but Rory was a little faster ;)

Comment: No Problems! Happy Coding!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try...

```
$('.submitform').on('click', function(e){
var values = $(this).siblings('input[name="test2"]').val();
console.log('values:'+ values);
e.preventDefault();
});
```